# Convergence of hypergeometric 2F1 with z=-1

Tags: convergence-divergence, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, mathematica

Encountering the hypergeometric function $_2F_1(4n+3,\ m+1;\ m+3;\ -1)$ where $n\in\textbf{N}$ and $m\in\{2,4,6,\ldots,4n-2\}$ I'm a bit confused about its convergence.

According to Erdélyi's "Higher Transcendental Functions Vol. 1," $_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ diverges if $|z|=1$ and $\text{Re}(a+b-c)\geq1$ (also confirmed by Wikipedia), and this is clearly my case. However in Mathematica it seems to converge; I get well-defined results for all values of $n$ and $m$ that I try, and plotting the function with $z\in\textbf{R}$ it seems fine around $z=-1$.

Does Mathematica perform some sort of analytic continuation or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, Mathematica performs an analytic continuation. It can be constructed using that the hypergeometric function of $z$ can be written as a linear combination of two hypergeometric functions of any of the other five cross-ratios ($1-z, 1/z, 1/(1-z), z/(z-1), (z-1)/z$). In your case $_2F_1$ can be written in terms of elementary functions, so the analytic continuation is even simpler.

Comment: I see! How would you write it as elementary functions? I've managed to write it as a Jacobi polynomial and as sums of binomial coefficients but something simpler would be welcome.

Comment: I meant Jacobi polynomials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by O.L. in the comments Mathematica does indeed use an analytic continuation.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, the radius of convergence is one. $z=-1$ is a boundary point and you need to handle it separately. To do this you need to look at [Abel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem).

Comment: @jorgen: I'll try to work on it and see if I can get a simplified form.